# Conversion type Integer Misunderstanding

Tags: vb.net

I am sorry for my bad english. I hope somebody could explain what the error `The conversion from type MySqlDataReader to type Integer is invalid` means.

I was sure that it was a simple 'Dim a Integer, but It is larger than that, or I am just been stupid.

My btnLogin_Click code:

```
Dim SQL As New MySQLHook
Dim loginResult As Integer

Dim User As TextBox = Me.Controls.Item("TextGebruikersNaam")
Dim Pass As TextBox = Me.Controls.Item("TextGebruikersPass")

If String.IsNullOrEmpty(User.Text) Or String.IsNullOrEmpty(Pass.Text) Then
    MsgBox("Voer een gebruikersnaam en wachtwoord in om verder te gaan.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Foutmelding")
    User.Focus()
Else
    loginResult = SQL.Results("SELECT * FROM tblgebruikers " & "WHERE GebruikersNaam='" & User.Text & "' AND " & "GebruikersPass='" & Pass.Text & "'")

    If loginResult = 1 Then
        ' Login was good, todo: add code here
    Else
        MsgBox("De gebruikersnaam of wachtwoord is onjuist. Probeer het opnieuw of vraag een nieuw wachtwoord aan.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Foutmelding")
        User.Text = ""
        Pass.Text = ""
        User.Focus()
    End If
End If
```

My Results code (SQL.Results is from As New MySQLHook)

```
Public Function Results(ByVal sql)
    Try
        Dim conn = Connect()

        Dim myAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
        Dim myCommand As New MySqlCommand()

        myCommand.Connection = conn
        myCommand.CommandText = sql

        myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand

        Dim myData As MySqlDataReader

        myData = myCommand.ExecuteReader()
        Return myData
    Catch myerror As MySqlException
        clsError.logMessage("De server retourneerde de volgende foutmelding: " & myerror.Message)
        Return DBNull.Value
    End Try
End Function
```

I olso tried using this function but it gave me the same error message:

```
Public Function num_results(ByVal sql)
Try
    Dim conn = Connect()

    Dim myAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim myCommand As New MySqlCommand()

    myCommand.Connection = conn
    myCommand.CommandText = sql
    myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand

    Dim myData As MySqlDataReader

    myData = myCommand.ExecuteReader()
    Return myData
Catch myerror As MySqlException
    clsError.logMessage("De server retourneerde de volgende foutmelding: " & myerror.Message)
    Return DBNull.Value
End Try
End Function
```

Why does this conversion error pop-ups? I was sure that 1 or 0 is self-explaining.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and turn Option Strict On, either by placing it at the top of your code file or in project setttings.  Your Results function doesn't have a return type specified and its parameter doesn't have a type either.  I don't see how this can even compile!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are creating a [data reader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx) and returning that. You need to read the integer from the `myData` variable before returning it.

So, instead of:

```
Return myData
```

You should be able to use:

```
Return myData.GetInt32(0)
```

The `0` in that statement identifies the column you want to read, and since you are returning a single column from your SQL query, it is in index 0.

Once you have fixed that, *please* google 'SQL injection' and 'parameterized SQL queries' before continuing. Having your app open to SQL injection is a serious risk.

Comment: Thank you for your code @driis. Once I edited myData with the `GetInt32(0)` I get the following error message: `Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'Integer' is not valid.`

Thank you for the SQL injection and parameterized SQL queries tips. I'll look into that today first thing.

Comment: That exception is because you try to return an Integer in the success case, and DBNull if not. A function must have the same return type for all cases. If you want to swallow the exception as you do now, consider returning `0` or `Nothing` in the catch clause.

Comment: Thank you driis, after going throught every line of code I finally get the error `Invalid attempt to access a field before calling Read()`. Now I am going to search how to solve that problem. Thank you for your patience.